# React native: ensure the event gets bubbled

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, events, event-handling

This must be trivial but I can't seem to figure out.

Context: I have a custom component to hide the keyboard everytime the user taps somewhere on the screen.

`HideKeyboard.tsx`

```
import {  TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export interface HideKeyboardProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function HideKeyboard(props: HideKeyboardProps) {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { Keyboard.dismiss(); }}>
            {props.children}
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

This works fine, but the problem arises when the user taps on a button on the screen. The expected behaviour would be - the keyboard dismisses and the click handler of the button gets executed.

But, because of the `HideKeyboard` control, the initial tap gets captured and is used to dismiss the keyboard and so the user has to tap again.

Is there a way to tackle this? Can we somehow execute the event in the onPress handler?

Comment: You could nest HideKeyboard inside a GestureHandlerRootView, although passing control over to a dynamic component could be tricky. You could also remove the HideKeyboard component, and wrap your onPress handlers in a function that calls Keyboard.dismiss.  Personally I would take the 2nd path

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to ensure the event gets bubbled when using TouchableWithoutFeedback is to use the `onPressOut` prop instead of the `onPress` prop. For example, you can change your HideKeyboard component to something like this:

```
export default function HideKeyboard(props: HideKeyboardProps) {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressOut={() => { Keyboard.dismiss(); }}>
            {props.children}
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
```

This will dismiss the keyboard when the user releases the touch, but will also allow the event to bubble up to the button’s
`onPress` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the behavior so that the tap event is not "consumed" by the `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Wrap your components with `View` instead of `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and use the `onStartShouldSetResponder` property of the `View` to detect touch events.

How to modify the `HideKeyboard` component:

```
import { View, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export interface HideKeyboardProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function HideKeyboard(props: HideKeyboardProps) {
  return (
    <View
      onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        return false; // Continue propagating the event
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```

By returning `false` from the `onStartShouldSetResponder` handler you're telling React Native to continue propagating the touch event to other views.

I think this gives you the behavior you're looking for - dismissing the keyboard when the user taps somewhere on the screen without interfering with button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Keyboard, View } from 'react-native';

export interface HideKeyboardProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function HideKeyboard(props: HideKeyboardProps) {
    return (
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
            {props.children}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

ScrollView's keyboardShouldPersistTaps property allows buttons to be clicked even when the keyboard is open.